# how to avoid deletion of folders under /run or /var/run

Tags: linux, rhel, process, tmpfs

the following folder --> `/var/run/kafka` , include the PID number of the kafka service

example

```
 ls -ltr /var/run/kafka/kafka.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop 7 Nov 10 14:14 /var/run/kafka/kafka.pid
```

when we reboot the **rhel 7  kafka machine** and machine started

we noticed that folder --> `/var/run/kafka` , isn't exist

therefore kafka service cant start

after short review we can see that `/run` is belong to `tmpfs` file-system , as the following example

```
 df -h | grep tmpfs
devtmpfs                   63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      63G  240K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      63G  4.1G   59G   7% /run
tmpfs                      63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                      13G  8.0K   13G   1% /run/user/0


df /var/run
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           65873044 4199192  61673852   7% /run
```

so we want to know - how we can avoid deletion of folder under /run ?

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: The question would rather be "How can we ensure the directory is created?". Since it's a tmpfs filesystem, it is _purposefully_ cleared on reboot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/var/run` is on tmpfs, which is an in-memory filesystems. Its contents are not saved when you reboot. You can't put anything there that needs to be saved across reboots.

The startup script or configuration for kafka is responsible for creating `/var/run/kafka`. If it's started by systemd, see [Create a directory under /var/run at boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot). If it's started via a shell script, just add `mkdir -p /var/run/kafka && chown kafka.hadoop /var/run/kafka`.

Comment: Good point that systemd can create the directory, but the version in CentOS 7 doesn’t have that feature, so it needs to use systemd-tmpfiles to do it.  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html